# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.Owin'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I did upgrading MVC5 and Web Api 2.2, I created MVC Web application. Inside of it, i added empty Web API defined as a child for my main project, all i want is to secure my data, 
routing worked well. but there are some data i want to get on my context, 
when try to get into ***localhost:34862/api/account/test*** i get an error

**Here's my codes in my ApiController**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IAccountUoW _iaUoW;

    public AccountController(IAccountUoW iaUoW)
    {
        _iaUoW = iaUoW;
    }

    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "test";
    }

    [Authorize]
    [Route("test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTourInfos()
    {
        var ctx = (OwinContext)Request.GetOwinContext();
        ClaimsPrincipal user = ctx.Authentication.User;
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = user.Claims;
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**my references i add from NuGet**

- Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2
- Owin
- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth

i also checked the references i added from my main project to my sub project it has the same version 
from my sub project

**here packages.config from sub project**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages
```

**Here's my packages.config from my main project**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.MVC5" version="3.2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi" version="3.2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity" version="3.5.1404.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

**here is my error**

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.Owin, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

From the package manager, i run also Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall, but still error is there, what i am missing? somebody help me? any answer will be appreciated thank you in advance.

Comment: tnx again for the comment,sorry i forgot only to add the same reference on the main and sub project, for example if you add Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost on the sub project, you must also add to main project with the same reference and version. otherwise reference not be load or you will got an error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem can be the Web Api 2.2 use the microsoft.owin 2.0.2 version. You can change the behavior in the web.config.

If your version of microsoft.owin is 3.0.0, in the line "bindingRedirect ", in "newVersion" set 3.0.0

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Regard,